# I want certain questions to appear base on the respond of another question

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a form with react. In the form i have questions that should appear depending on the respond of a previous question.

For Example

**Question- Do you have children?**
**Answers Yes or No is a picker**

If the answer is **Yes** then the follow up question should be **How many children ?**

If the answer is **No** then the follow up question should be **Do you want to adopt ?**.

```
<Grid item xs={3} className={classes.item}>
<PublishedComponent
pubRef="niue.YesOrNoPicker"
label="AddDiafForm.children"
value={edited.children}
onChange={v => this.updateAttribute("children", v)}
/>
</Grid>

<Grid item xs={1} className={classes.item}>
module="DiaForm" label="AddDiafForm.howmany?"
value={edited.howmany}
onChange={v => this.updateAttribute("howmany", v)}
/>
</Grid>

<Grid item xs={1} className={classes.item}>
<TextInput
module="DiaForm" label="AddDiafForm.adopt?"
value={edited.adopt}
onChange={v => this.updateAttribute("adopt", v)}
/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: So what is _your_ question?

Comment: Use ```switch``` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use ternary operators. For example:

```
const [answer, setAnswer] = useState('yes');
...
return (
...
{answer === 'yes' ? (
<input placeholder='How many children ?'>) : (
<input placeholder='Do you want to adopt ?'>)}
)
```

Eventually this could change depending on your code.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should react state to check if the answer is "yes" or "no" and render the component there after.

```
export default function App() {
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      Do you have children?
      <div>
        <input
          checked={answer === "yes"}
          value="yes"
          type="radio"
          onChange={(e) => setAnswer(e.target.value)}
        />{" "}
        Yes
        <input
          checked={answer === "no"}
          value="no"
          type="radio"
          onChange={(e) => setAnswer(e.target.value)}
        />{" "}
        No
      </div>
      <div>
        {answer === "yes" ? (
          <div>How many?</div>
        ) : answer === "no" ? (
          <div>Do you want to adopt?</div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to create JSON structure which will map questions based on response.

so, based on response from user you can show what will be the set of questions needs to render.

By, this way you can achieve what you wanted!

Ex.

```
const responseMapping = {
   [question-ID]: {
     [response1]: [que-id1, que-id2...],
     [response2]: [que-id3, que-id4...],
   }
}

and in utils:

const getQuestions(question-ID, response) {
     const questionMapping = responseMapping[question-ID];
     if(questionMapping) {
       return allQuestions.filter(...); //filter based on response
     } else {
       return commonQuestions; //logic for getting next common question based on question id
     }
}
```

I hope this will be the helpful to you! **Happy coding...**

Comment: There's no JSON in your "answer". Just some syntax errors...

Comment: Yes instead of JSON structure, I should say object mapping. And, related to syntax error, I was just giving example not full-proof coding, to understand what I want to say and He can implement mapping in his own way.

Comment: @Andreas, this forum should be only for help developers with our own experience and not to go each comment of reviewers and dislike the comments and answer. I hope, further, you will be focused on solving queries only!

Comment: SO is not a forum. It's a Q&A. And therefor an answer should actually be an answer that solves the problem from the question. A comment with syntax errors is not an answer...